# QFutureWatcher doesn't deliver a finished() signal after switching to another future. Is this behaviour documented?

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, qt5

I have a class with methods `void MyClass::reset()`, `void MyClass::doWork()`, that look something like this:

```
void MyClass::reset()
{
    _abortFlag = true; // class field of type QAtomicInt
    _watcher.waitForFinished(); // class field type QFutureWatcher<void>
    _abortFlag = false;
    
    // some code

    _watcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::doWork));
}
```

```
void MyClass::doWork()
{
    while (someCondition && !_abortFlag)
    {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

and a connection

```
connect(&_watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, this, &MyClass::mySlot);
```

But after watched running future finishes in line `_watcher.waitForFinished();` and another future starts to be watched in line `watcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::doWork));`, `finished()` signal from the first future is not processed when the program returns to the event loop. Is this documented behaviour? Can I rely on this behaviour in my program?

Comment: I think you cannot rely on this behavior as it seems undocumented.

Comment: Apparently each future needs own watcher. Unsure if it worth to code a reply other than getting higher score. It is on the surface.